# scala, adding an implicit function to the Map class, fails with "structural refinement may not refer to an abstract"

Tags: scala

```
  import scala.language.implicitConversions

  implicit def extendedMap[A,B](map: Map[A,B]) = new {
    def updatedOption(key: A, valueOption: Option[B]) = valueOption match {
      case Some(value) => map.updated(key, value)
      case None => map - key
    }
  }

  var kv = Map.empty[String, String]
  kv.updatedOption("k1", Some("v1")

  //removing the implicit keyword, and explicitly calling the conversion also fails:
  extendedMap(kv).updatedOption("k1", Some("v1")
```

error compiler message:

```
Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
    def updatedOption(key: A, valueOption: Option[B]) = valueOption match {

                  ^
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Workaround: `implicit class ExtendedMap[A,B](map: Map[A,B]) { def updatedOption(k: A, v: Option[B]) = v.map{ map.updated(k, _) }.getOrElse(map - k) }`.

Comment: using implicit class instead of implicit def works, thanks. please post it again as an answer, so that i can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done, but note that it's a workaround. I can't tell you why you can't do it with abstract type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since scala `2.10` you should not use `implicit def` for `extension methods` - use `implicit class` instead. See [SIP-13](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/implicit-classes.html). With `implicit class` you should not import `language.implicitConversions`:

```
implicit class ExtendedMap[A,B](map: Map[A,B]) {
  def updatedOption(k: A, v: Option[B]) = v.map{ map.updated(k, _) }.getOrElse(map - k)
}
```

Actually it should work with `implicit def` with explicit class declaration like this:

```
class ExtendedMap[A,B](map: Map[A,B]) {
  def updatedOption(k: A, v: Option[B]) = v.map{ map.updated(k, _) }.getOrElse(map - k)
}
implicit def toExtendedMap[A,B](map: Map[A,B]): ExtendedMap[A,B] =
  new ExtendedMap[A, B](map)
```